# pyspark gives error for describe() method when the column name as a '.' in it

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am importing data using pyspark dataframe from a csv file with header names have `.` in them e.g., x.name. It displays correctly. However, when I am trying to view its summary using describe method, I get an error - looks like whenever the column name has a `.` in it I have this error, else it works fine. Could someone please suggest how to resolve this?
I tried pandas and it works without any issues.

Thank you very much.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRmjZ.jpg)